# How to remove white line from center on screen (compiz) 15.04

Tags: compiz

After trying to change snapping windows to wobbly windows (compiz), my PC screen flashing and when it came back on it had no menu bar or side bar. I was able to fix them with sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ & sudo setsid unity, but there was also a white or silver vertical line on the center of the screen. I'm not able to get it fix.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?